# get time between two times of the day

Tags: iphone, objective-c, time, nsdate

I've already tried with NSDate but with no luck.
I want the difference between for example 14:10 and 18:30.

Hours and minutes.

I Hope you can help me shouldn't be that complicated :)

Comment: how do you want difference to be presented? NSString, NSNumber, int, float, another NSDate?

Answer (score 30):

There's no need to calculate this by hand, take a look at `NSCalendar`. If you want to get the hours and minutes between two dates, use something like this:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:unitFlags
                                                    fromDate:firstDate
                                                      toDate:otherDate
                                                     options:0];
[gregorianCalendar release];
```

You now have the hours and minutes as NSDateComponents and can access them as `NSIntegers` like `[components hour]` and `[components minute]`. This will also work for hours between days, leap years and other fun stuff.

Answer (score 19):

Here's my quick solution:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"14:10"];
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:@"18:09"];
NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
int hours = (int)interval / 3600;             // integer division to get the hours part
int minutes = (interval - (hours*3600)) / 60; // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes
NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", hours, minutes];
```

Comment: thanks! mhh the compiler gives me an error that initWithDateFormat... does not exist...

Comment: sorry, I wrote that with the Mac OS SDK.  Corrected for iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 12):

The NSDate class has a method timeIntervalSinceDate that does the trick.

```
NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate];
```

NSTimeInterval is a double that represents the seconds between the two times.

Comment: You then have to do your own calculations to turn the seconds into hours and minutes. Then you have to convert those numbers into a string. It's trivial but it comes up a lot. I suggest creating utility class to do this and keep it handy.

Comment: okay thanks! now i have the seconds so to get hours i would divide through 3600. then i get 1546521531.

Can you give me any hints please?

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *duration = [self calculateDuration:oldTime secondDate:currentTime];

- (NSString *)calculateDuration:(NSDate *)oldTime secondDate:(NSDate *)currentTime
{
    NSDate *date1 = oldTime;
    NSDate *date2 = currentTime;

    NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

    int hh = secondsBetween / (60*60);
    double rem = fmod(secondsBetween, (60*60));
    int mm = rem / 60;
    rem = fmod(rem, 60);
    int ss = rem;

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hh,mm,ss];

    return str;
}
```