# In iPhone, how to calculate the passed time?

Tags: iphone

I want know the passed time that also is between two date,

for example , `dateTime1` and `dateTime2` , I want a function like  `getPassedTime( time1, time2)`

The function result should be like `1 day 3 hours 12 minutes 10 second` or just `40 second`.

I know that the method `timeIntervalSinceDate` of the class `NSDate` can be use, but the problem is convert to details string that could be easy understand.

Anyone can help? share some code will be appreciate or give me some tip if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use NSCalendar and [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Code snippet in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792512/objective-c-get-time-between-two-times-of-the-day).

Answer (score 1):

Use the timeIntervalSinceDate method of the NSDate class:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600"];

NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2001-03-28 12:38:52 +0600"];

NSTimeInterval *timePassed = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```