# Time elapsed when battery increased of 5%

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, battery, batterylevel

I would like to know if there's a way to get the time elapsed when the battery increased of 5%. For example, how can I know how much time elapsed between 60% and 65% ? I think I could do this with NSTimer, but I'm not able to do this, can someone help me ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: No need for NSTimer, use NSDate. Create one when the battery reaches 60% and another at 65% then compare them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this for a Mac, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272552/battery-status-in-osx) for how to get battery life in Mac;

If you are doing this for iOS, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469549/iphone-calculating-battery-life?rq=1) for how to get battery life in iOS.

Simply use your NSTimer to fire the function to get the battery life every x seconds and when it gets to 60%, capture a timestamp with `NSDate`, then when it gets to 65%, capture another timestamp and compare the two timestamps to get the time difference: [SO question: how to get time between 2 NSDate objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792512/get-time-between-two-times-of-the-day).

Good luck.

EDIT:

All the methods to get the battery percentage are in either the first or second link based on your platform. If you want it to determine the time between now, and 5% up/down:

```
//both percent and date should be properties or instance variables (NSDate and float, respectively)
//You should probably also make the timer one as well, so you can stop it in any method with [tmr invalidate];
date = [NSDate date];
percent = [self getBatteryPercent];

NSTimer* tmr = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(someMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (float)getBatteryPercent
{
    //You'll have to get this code from one of those methods (first or second link)
}

- (void)someMethod
{
    float newPercent = [self getBatteryPercent];
    if(percent - newPercent == 5.0 || percent - newPercent == -5.0)
    {
        //Get the time between timestamps
        NSDate* newDate = [NSDate date];
        //See third link for how to get the time difference between date and newDate
    }
}
```

The rest is up to you.

Comment: Hi, that of 60% was only an example. I need to know how much time elapsed between the current percentage to 5% more or less. Could you help me with a sample ? Thank you.

Comment: @GiulianoZanco All the work has basically been done for you. All you have to do is make some minor changes.